# Printing values to new line in excel

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm currently looping though web pages and pulling the values from each `<td>` element and appending them in a list as text, which I want to export into an Excel spreadsheet.

The problem is I want to copy the values from all the different webpages into their own row on the spreadsheet but I can only figure out how to append all the data to a list before I send to excel, so this is printing all the data to 1 row.

I really need each web page on a separate row in excel but cant figure out how to write it.

This is what I have -

```
import requests, bs4, xlsxwriter

td_text = []
row = 0
col = 0

def print_table():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        base_link = 'http://some/website/%d' % (i)
        try:
            res = requests.get(base_link)
            res.raise_for_status()
            techSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
            table = techSoup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table borderless'})
            for div in table:
                rows = div.findAll('td')
                for string in rows:
                    td_text.append(string.text)
                    print(string.text)
                    send_excel(row, col)



        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
            print('Error: Invalid Website \n\n.')

def send_excel(row, col):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('list.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    row += 1
    worksheet.write_row(row, col, td_text)

    workbook.close()

print_table()
```

All the data is pulled from websites correctly.

I can see my issue that all data is appended to list before I call `write_row()`, but I'm not sure how I would write it so each website is written to the spreadsheet as it iterates through the loop.

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing it, but in the `print_table` function, you never change `row`?  Once you set it at `0`, it never gets updated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  To make your code a good [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), eliminate the request code and seed the main with a small example of the kind of results you'd get.  Then we can help you learn how to process it.  As it is, we can't run your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about where your code is executing (in terms of local scope and your loops) you'll realize that you're opening and closing this file dozens of times (which is very inefficient), never incrementing your row counter, and never clearing your text data between requests. You only need to open and close the file once, and you'll want to write the row just once for each set of data. Try something like this:

```
import requests, bs4, xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('list.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for i in range(1, 10):
    td_text = []
    base_link = 'http://some/website/%d' % (i)
    try:
        res = requests.get(base_link)
        res.raise_for_status()
        techSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
        table = techSoup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table borderless'})
        for div in table:
            rows = div.findAll('td')
            for string in rows:
                td_text.append(string.text)
        worksheet.write_row(i, 0, td_text)

    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        print('Error: Invalid Website \n\n.')

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great help and exactly what I needed! Much appreciated : )